# Calculating interest rate with a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing this assignment:

> When a bank has financial problems the government can return a
> client's deposit if it is less than 700,000. The interest rate for a
> particular deposit is 7.1% a year. The percentages are paid to the
> same deposit at the end of the year and a new value of the interest is
> calculated.
>
> Find out how many years it will take for the sum of the deposit to
> exceed the value protected by the government.
>
> The input format:
>
> The initial sum of the deposit. It is guaranteed that the value will
> be between 50,000 and 700,000.
>
> The output format:
>
> The number of years.

Here is the code I got:

```
deposit = int(input())
year = 0
while deposit <= 700000:
    deposit = (deposit * pow((7.1 / 100 + 1), year))
    year += 1

print((year - 1))
```

It works in my IDE, but the website keeps insisting it's wrong. What is the problem?

Comment: When you say "it works in my IDE", do you mean "there are no errors", or "it gives the correct results"?

Comment: It outputs the answer the website wants, but it tells me I solved it in an incorrect way

Comment: Does the website want you to print the result? Many of them expect a function and a return statement... Just a thought

Comment: I agree with @mkrieger1. You are not calculating interest for each year in the loop. Instead you are calculating 1 year of interest for the first iteration, 2 years of interest for the second iteration, 3 years of interest for third iteration and on. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Hmm when I was younger, I would has said that the formula for compound interests was either `deposit_n1 = deposit_n * (1 + 7.1 /100)` (one year from previous one) or `deposit_n = deposit_0 * (1+7.1/100) ** n` (an arbitrary year from the initial deposit). But yours seems to be a strange mix of them...

Comment: @MSH I didn't say that.

Comment: It wants me to get the out 2 years, but it has all these different tests that make sure I just can't type print(2) and get the answer correctly

Comment: Does it show the constraints of the test?

Comment: Nope it says we need to figure them out themselves :) I literally spent 2 hours on this question and I still didnt get it right

Comment: 1 You need take input in a variable..
2 While the input is less than 700 000, multiply the variable with 0.071 (7.1%) and add to the current value of the variable.
3 Add 1 year, per iteration.
4 print how many years.
this was a hint from one of the users that solved the question

Comment: You see you didn't multiply the deposit with the interest rate. You raised the interest rate to the power of the year and then multiplied it.

Comment: How would I implement that into my code?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
deposit = (deposit * (pow((1+7.1/100,year)))
```

Comment: What does this line mean? How does it answer the question?

Comment: It's the rate from the assignment

Comment: Yes, but it's not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the task correctly:

```
import math

rate = 7.1 / 100
limit = 700

deposit = int(input('Input deposit (50-700):'))

year = math.ceil(math.log(limit / deposit, rate + 1))

print(f'years to achieve {limit} = {year}')
print(f'checked sum of the deposit after {math.ceil(year)} years = {deposit * pow(rate + 1, year)}')
```

Prints:

```
Input deposit (50-700):256
years to achieve 700 = 15
checked sum of the deposit after 15 years = 716.2786852658132
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this line instead
deposit+= 0.071 * deposit

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).